# Docker --ssh flag - Host key verification failed

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to use Docker to build an image for me importing an npm package hosted in a private github repo: `"mypackage": "git@github.com:myaccount/myrepo.git#v0.0.2"`

This works fine locally since I have SSH access, but obviously my Docker container doesn't. I've followed the following guides to implement this using some ssh forwarding enabled in 18.09:

https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds

Using the following docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM alpine

# Install ssh client and git
RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

# Download public key for github.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Clone private repository
RUN --mount=type=ssh npm install
```

Then, running `docker build --ssh default .` fails with the following error:

```
#13 1.309 npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
#13 1.309 npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#13 1.309 npm ERR!
#13 1.309 npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#13 1.309 npm ERR! and the repository exists.
#13 1.310 npm ERR!
#13 1.310 npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I'm following this documentation to the letter but am having no luck. Am I missing something? I'm on OSX, but this fails with the same error in my Travis environment as well. Help!

Comment: Do you have `ssh-agent` running or are you just using the default `.ssh/id_rsa` key?

Comment: Hmm, just using the default; or at least I think. How can I check?

Comment: That `--ssh` flag forwards connections from the builder to `ssh-agent`. It doesn't share your `.ssh` folder where the key is located. You need to run `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Does it run as a daemon or something? Is that part of a command to be run in the Dockerfile?

Comment: It runs in the background, yes. Just run `ssh-agent` before using `docker build --ssh default`. The default settings should match.

Answer (score 3):

This has worked for me.

Dockerfile extraction:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
...
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 /root/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
COPY development/config /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/config
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone **MY_PVT_REPOSITORY**
```

This is the content of the development/config file you can see being copied at the third line

```
Host bitbucket.org
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile **MY LOCAL PATH**/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The tricky thing is that you have to put the host file path to id_rsa, not the one on docker (like /home/fabio/.ssh/id_rsa and NOT /root/.ssh/id_rsa)

Then just launch

```
  ssh-agent
  export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
  docker build --ssh default -f development/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Did the trick for me Fabio, thank-you so much for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, Mr. Filippi!

FYI guys, you can check this article [How to Set Up SSH Keys on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04)

My implementation based on Fabio's comment looks like this:

```
mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh
echo "$KNOWNHOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
echo "$CONFIG_SETTINGS" >> ~/.ssh/config
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/config
```

In KNOWNHOSTS GitLab variable I have saved the output of "ssh-keyscan www.example.com"

In SSH_PRIVATE_KEY I am storing my SSH PRIVATE KEY for the specified user.

In CONFIG_SETTINGS I have the following:

```
Host www.example.com
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```